# XML asset fails to load using https

Tags: ssl, xml

The wp-admin are of my site is available via https only; for that reason any use of `get_template_directory_uri();` in the admin area generates a url as such https://mysite.co.uk/...

I am able to successfully enqueue scripts and styles using `get_template_directory_uri();` however when I attempt to use `simplexml_file_load();` to access a local xml document in the admin area of the site, the file fails to load.

I can get around this by hardcoding a non https version of my theme directory, but for obvious reasons, this isn't practical.

**Summary:**

`simplexml_load_file(get_template_directory_uri().'/myxml.xml');` - does not work
`simplexml_load_file('https://mysite.co.uk/my-theme/myxml.xml');` - does not work
`simplexml_load_file('http://mysite.co.uk/my-theme/myxml.xml');` - does work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case this helps anyone in the future:

The problem was not a WordPress issue, it was a server configuration issue.

Useful explanation on checking which stream wrappers are enabled on your server (used this to make sure https was enabled on my server) [Enable Stream Wrappers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2305954/how-to-enable-https-stream-wrappers)

Someone with the same issue found that their certificate failed to verify:
[Certificate Verification Fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32621929/error-when-loading-external-xml-file-with-php-via-https-ssl3-get-server-certif)

The issue was fixed by our hosting provider, with the following explanation:

> The problem is caused by the the self signed certificate on the
>   server. We could either allow the self signed certificate in the php
>   setup or load a valid SSL certificate.
>
> The issue was fixed by creating a self signed certificate which
>   matches the Openssl common name. This fixed all libxml errors

Answer (score 0):

You've loaded the `xml` file using an URL of your own web server. While your solution fixes the problem, it wasn't necessary to load the `xml` using URL (HTTP or HTTPS) in the first place. Since it's on the same server, you could've loaded the `xml` file using file PATH instead.

> ***Note:*** `get_template_directory_uri()` function returns URL, whereas, `get_template_directory()` function returns local file PATH.

So instead of:

```
simplexml_load_file( get_template_directory_uri() . '/myxml.xml' );
```

CODE, you can use:

```
simplexml_load_file( get_template_directory() . '/myxml.xml' );
```

This way, there will be no local URL issue at all & it's much faster.